# How to identify Google-Forms em Python?

Tags: python, forms

How could I determine how many answers I want? How do I use options with "&"?

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdpiraT-JU6B5GOQ5ejCOBp7kNn0-MU4K3Vw30umxzEi7mVwg/viewform

Comment: can't you just count all components below `freebirdFormviewerViewItemList` ?

Comment: However, it does not recognize the "&" (ampersand) @ZKDev